# Why would a DAC have both Vcc and V+ power supply?

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, dac

I'm trying to understand the datasheet for the [AD5535B](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5535B.pdf) DAC. I think I can understand why there would be a DVcc (digital Vcc) and AVcc (analog Vcc) to prevent digital switching noise to enter the analog circuitry and to allow maybe 3.3V digital signals. In addition, there is a high voltage input Vpp. However, on the analog side we find both an AVcc and V+. They have the exact same voltage ratings. The datasheet has only this to say,

> If the number of supplies must be reduced, bring all supplies back separately and make a provision
> on the board via a link option to drive the AVCC and V+ pins from the same supply.

I guess this means that they recommend to still have separate power supply connections to the eventual PCB, but allow them to be tied together if needed. But that still gets me no closer to why one would want them separate at all.

What is the explanation for these two separate supplies? Why should I bother? The [manual](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/EVAL-AD5535BSDZ_UG-730.pdf) for the evaluation board just specifies to use a single power supply for V+ and AVcc.

Comment: That's an odd chip for a special use like driving a bunch of MEMS mirrors at 50-200 volts.  You might want to read the supporting materials, study the reference design, etc and see if that offers clues to what parts of the internal functionality each supply powers beyond the minimal information in the data sheet.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I happen to want to drive a large bunch of piezo-electric actuators so it actually seems ideal for the job except for one or two questions which I'm trying to figure out now (I'm a mechanical engineer so I'm a little bit out of my depth here).

Comment: Definitely, definitely study the reference design then

Comment: @ChrisStratton They have an evaluation board which tells you to just connect everything to a single 5V supply. The application example doesn't even mention AVcc.

Comment: The EVAL-AD5535EB has no less than seven banana jacks for the power connection, there's a reason for that and it would be worth finding the manual.  Connecting everything to a 5v supply won't even work as the *minimum* for the Vpp input is 50 volts.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sorry, everything but Vpp of course.

Comment: You could always follow the advice they quoted, in bringing things back separately and joining them only at the feed point to preserve your options.  Generally though, this sounds complex and expensive enough that it would be worth getting an EE involved in your project to make sure that the layout of the board is good in terms of electrical integrity, etc.  If you go ahead and do it yourself, be very conservative, use lots of copper, and try to preserve your options to try things in different ways without having the respin the board. See if there are xray views of the EVB.  Even draw over it.

Comment: In short, unless you are prepared to do a number of respins to optimize things, do what they did on the EVB, even if it's not clear *why*.  That applies to geometry and layers, not just conceptual connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Having separate supplies allows for the ability to change the range of the DAC output and have it based on a precision voltage reference. With 24-bit DACs this is a necessity.

Another problem is sometimes amplifiers that are internal to DACs have common mode ranges that necessitate the VCC supply being larger than the reference voltage supply range

Answer (score 0):

AVcc supplies the DACs, V+ supplies the output drivers.

AVcc is supposed to be very stable, and power draw there should be minimal, while a bit of fluctuation on V+ is inconsequential because the driver stages correct for it -- but this supply needs to be able to supply more current.

If you tie them together, loading one output will slightly change the DAC value on the others, so you get a bit of coupling between outputs through there.

Comment: Actually Vpp supplies the 50-200 volt output drivers, making it a bit less clear what V+ does.  Perhaps some intermediate stage.

Comment: Ah, then I have misread the datasheet